# How Do I Assign Different Functions/ClickEvents To Buttons Inside A DatagridColumn In WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have successfully created a DataGrid with WPF (C#) and bonded the buttons...However I now would like to bind a different event to each individual button instead. I plan to rename the buttons and open different file locations on my PC.

## C#

```
wpfCrudEntities _db = new wpfCrudEntities();
public static DataGrid datagrid;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load();
}

private void Load()
{
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.members.ToList();
    datagrid = myDataGrid;
}

private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InsertPage Ipage = new InsertPage();
    Ipage.ShowDialog();
}
private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Id = (myDataGrid.SelectedItem as member).id;
    UpdatePage Upage = new UpdatePage(Id);
    Upage.ShowDialog();
}
private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Id = (myDataGrid.SelectedItem as member).id;
    var deleteMemeber = _db.members.Where(m => m.id == Id).Single();
    _db.members.Remove(deleteMemeber);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.members.ToList();
}
```

}

## XAML

```xml
    <Window x:Class="wappppa.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wappppa"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <DockPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding gender}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Action" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button x:Name="insertBtn" Content="Insert" Click="insertBtn_Click"/>
                            <Button x:Name="updateBtn" Content="Update" Click="updateBtn_Click"/>
                            <Button x:Name="deleteBtn" Content="Delete" Click="deleteBtn_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You don't need to bind different events for each button, just use the sender object.

Comment: @mahdi-farhani how exactly do I do this?

Comment: Can you post some code around your buttons?

Comment: @andrew-keepcoding Yes, I have just uploaded the main c# code

Comment: I assume that you have 3 buttons (insert, update, delete) in XAML, right? Assign to them just shouldn't suffice? Or you want to do something else?

Comment: Also posting related XAML code should help.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I just posted the related XAML code. Yes I got those 3 buttons in XAML. I want to open a different folder depending on which button I click. I will rename the buttons, so there are just there as a dummies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample project to show you how you one way of use the `DataGrid` with the **MVVM** design.

I also added a `Call ViewModel` button just to show you how you can call commands in the ViewModel.

**Caution**
Unfortunately, there's a bug and you need to add [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/378) to your project file. This bug will go away soon I guess.

**Member.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid;

public class Member
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Gender { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid;

// This class needs to be "partial"
// so the CommunityToolkit's source generator can create code for you.
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // The source generator will auto-create a
    // "Member" property with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Member>? members = new()
    {
        new Member() { Name = "Ted", Gender="Male" },
        new Member() { Name = "Tracy", Gender="Female"},
        new Member() { Name = "Marshal", Gender = "Male" },
        new Member() { Name = "Lily", Gender = "Female" },
        new Member() { Name = "Robin", Gender = "Female" },
        new Member() { Name = "Barney", Gender = "Male" },
        new Member() { Name = "Ranjit", Gender = "Male" },
    };

    // The source generator will auto-create a "CallViewModelCommand" command.
    [RelayCommand]
    private void CallViewModel(Member member)
    {
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();

    private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button button && button.DataContext is Member member)
        {
            string name = member.Name;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfAppDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDataGrid"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="ThisWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="MyDataGrid"
            x:FieldModifier="public"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ColumnWidth="*"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=ViewModel.Members}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding ID}"
                    Header="ID" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    Header="Name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Gender}"
                    Header="Gender" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="Action" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button
                                    x:Name="InsertButton"
                                    Click="InsertButton_Click"
                                    Content="Insert" />
                                <Button
                                    x:Name="UpdateButton"
                                    Click="UpdateButton_Click"
                                    Content="Update" />
                                <Button
                                    x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                    Click="DeleteButton_Click"
                                    Content="Delete" />
                                <Button
                                    Command="{Binding ViewModel.CallViewModelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Content="ViewModel Command" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This looks promising and it also shows no errors after implementing it in VS. What exactly could I possible put into the fields "// This is your item for that row. // You just need to cast it if you want to use it. " I just started out, and I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Using the MVVM pattern you define a ViewModel for your rows.
Then you can use a CommandBinding to bind the Button Click event to the ViewModel of the respective row.

In your case this would be the Member class that needs to be wrapped in a MemberViewModel where the 3 coammnds are defined.

Comment: "use a CommandBinding to bind the Button Click event to the ViewModel" - Button has   dedicated Command and CommandParameter properties

Answer (score 0):

When a button click event fired you can access convert the sender object to a button and do whatever you want.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedButton= (Button)sender;
        // Do whatever you want
    }
```

Comment: So, I just looked into it and I also have it like that. Now I don't understand how I can use this to make the button event different for each button type in the row, since as for now it appears (as you can see in my code posted above) that the event will be the same for every button. For example if I determine an event for the update button, all update buttons will have the same events. This is not what I am seeking. *It might be that I don't get what this sender does (I am looking into it right now)...

Comment: All buttons call the same event with a different sender, each button can have different command and command parameters. with a simple if or switch you can make different behaviour for each button.